# Who is going to Ethereum DevCon #2 in Shanghai to promote Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, site-promotion, stackexchange, devcon

The [Ethereum DevCon #2](https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon/) will be held on Sept 19-21, 2016 in Shanghai, China.

Around 800 Ethereum developers and enthusiasts will be around to discuss newest advances in technology and trends in web 3.0 development.

Who is going to Ethereum DevCon #2 in Shanghai to promote Stack Exchange?

How could we promote Ethereum Stack Exchange on DevCon #2?

Answer (score 5):

I plan on promoting Stack.Exchange in some way when I attend. Not sure yet. It will likely be connected to [Eth.Champs](http://www.ethchamps.org).

Answer (score 5):

I will be there too as it turns out.
We could announce a *Stackexchange Dinner* where people from the SE community gather. Here is the Plan:

@home:

- finding a neat restaurant around the bund, not too crowded
- finding a nice waterhole for after dinner drinks
- printing flyers for the event

@shanhai:

- distributing flyers on the conf
- meet at the restaurant chat about Ethereum and Meta
- Eat, get drunk and be friends.

What do you think? Help welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I'll be attending. What can I do to help promote ESE?

Answer (score 3):

I will be there, but I am collecting the needed information about the Visa process. It is the first time I go there. besides, I am willing to meet some stack exchange active members personaly, to discuss what's new and what we should prepare for the future... cool :D