# Ethereum Stack Exchange is featured at the DevCon #2

Tags: discussion, devcon, events

The Ethereum Developer Conference *DevCon #2* will be held this September in [Shanghai](https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon/).

The Ethereum team kindly reserved a spot on the DevCon website to promote and link back to the [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) Q&A site.

[image: devcon website screenshot]

Thank you, dear Ethereum Foundation, for supporting our Ethereum Q&A beta and thanks for waiving the sponsorship fees for this community spot.

Anyways, see you in [China](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/216/87)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you Ethereum Foundation!